# Open standard iOS keyboard, instead of custom one

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard, uiresponder

I am calling `becomeFirstResponder`, and showing the keyboard with it.

```
[inputTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

However, it shows the custom keyboard that is installed on test device.  Is there a way to show iOS Standard Keyboard for Number Pad?

[image]

Comment: txtFiled.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault

Comment: I have to display numbers only, so I am using UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad.

Comment: For keyword Have you used any thirdparty keyword.If you are using than please check keyword subview

Comment: Swiftkey is installed on one of the test devices. This problem occurs on that phone. I want to show default number pad for all devices whether they installed custom keyboard or not.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer list originally at: [Prevent custom keyboard in textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020956/prevent-custom-keyboard-in-textfield)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:(NSString *)extensionPointIdentifier {
    if ([extensionPointIdentifier isEqualToString: UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```